# create active record in rails except particular key in hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, hash

I am searching from quite a long time now and I cannot figure out how to create active record in rails with hash except particular key in the hash.

What I am currently doing is

```
  ingre = {:name => "pepper", :std_qty => 2, :quantity => 20}

  quantity = ingre[:quantity]
    ingre.delete(:quantity)
  ingredient = Ingredient.new(ingre)
  ingredient.save!
```

I do not have `quantity` column in my `ingredients` table, there are only `name` and `std_qty`. and I don't want to use delete because it is not very concise way. I know that there is some way where in we can avoid key quantity while building the object `ingredient` instead of deleting externally. can anyone tell me what it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. You just need to use hash.except(:key_name)

so above code will turn out to be

```
ingre = {:name => "pepper", :std_qty => 2, :quantity => 20}
ingredient = Ingredient.new(ingre.except(:quantity))
ingredient.save!
```

Comment: You could use `create!` instead of `new` and `save!`. Saves one expression.